# Can't use a Chrome Extension for Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, shortcut

I've been trying to make my workflow faster on Overleaf. Months ago I installed [Overleaf Commander](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/overleaf-commander/bmlefjcamijlejhefedobjohbiekkemb?hl=it), which uses a keyboard shortcut (Ctrl + P as a standard) to access other files in the project. This was a great help but since yesterday it has stopped working, could anyone using Overleaf confirm this is case for them too? I haven't changed anything in my settings and the last Chrome update was a couple of days ago.

As an alternative, I tried using [SLext](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/slext/jlajbdlfgkklpjdgnhajdohfjbihming?hl=en), but I can't understand how it works or if it's working at all. For instance I can't use the "Open command palette" (Alt + P as standard) and all commands related to tabs. In fact, I can't manage to open a single tab and I understand how this is done. I can however use the "Surround selection in LaTeX command", which means the extension isn't completely broken.

This is really hindering my work and I didn't know where else to ask, hope to get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

developer at Overleaf here.

We've deployed some major changes to the file tree earlier this week. While the changes not super visible to end-user, the underlying code has changed a lot and I'm afraid this may have broken the extension.

Unfortunately, we do not have the capacity to provide support for such extensions and cannot guarantee backwards-compatibility. You may want to contact the extension's developer to let them know.

I've added a vote for this feature in our ideas tracker.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At least I know what's happened. It was driving me crazy since I though I had done something. Hope the feature gets added eventually. Thanks again!